# AWS Stack and resources name handling. A discussion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, aws-serverless

I just started using AWS for serverless projects. Ive done some tests and easily I came across to what I think is a very common issue when you are in a normal development flow with a team. The case is the following:

You may have "main" stack that matches the "main" state of the branch. This could be like the "demo/production" environment where all final changes are deployed and we can test our State machine flow.

Lets say that as part of this workflow, you have common resources like DynamoDb tables, ApiGateways, etc. Each of them created by CDK and thus, with a "name/identifier" manually set: i.e: "Proposals" table, "ApiGateWayStack", etc

When you deploy this main stack and, until you destroy it, all this resources are linked to that stack and thus, if you are working on a new feature and want to test the normal flow, you have to set manually new namings for all the resources or they will collide when you tried to deploy this new "versions" of the stack.

Currently we tried several options: change naming for every resource until integration with main branch, set a prefix on application.properties and set it to every resource so its final name is the concatenation of the prefix and the former name of the stack, using the main stack name + the target resource name, etc.

All this approaches fix the problem when deploying the idk with secondary branches but is there a better way to do this? Im curious about what other approaches people do because I think this is a very common scenario that happens all the time.

Thanks in advance

Documentation, forum workarounds, etc